# Validation Message not cleared after user fix value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view modal for chang password that contains NewPassword field and look like this:

```
[Display(Name = "NewPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
[RegularExpression(@"(?=^[^\s]{8,16}$)((?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[^\w\d\s])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?[^\w\d\s])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])|(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^\w\d\s]))^.*", ErrorMessageResourceName = "NewPasswordFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

and in view it's like this

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Resources.NewPassword })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
```

after the user enter a wrong value the Validation Message appear,
but after the user fix value and lost the input field the Validation Message not cleared
how someone have an idea how to correct this?

Comment: Are you sure the 'fixed' value is valid for the regular expression?

Comment: yes ,and in aother validate error it's cleared

Comment: I know that the fixed value is valid becouse in submit it's arrived to server